# Erro ao criar webForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

Eu tenho um winForm que eu estou passando para WebForm, criei meu WebForm e fui passando os itens aos poucos primeiro coloquei uns botões pra ver se ia funcionar, adicionei as referências, mas uma delas ta dando problema, parece que ele ele não encontra, será que alguém pode me dar uma luz de como solucionar isso?

WinForm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Flir.Atlas.Image;
    using Flir.Atlas.Live.Device;
    using Flir.Atlas.Live.Discovery;

    namespace DualCamera
    {
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private Camera _cam1;

        private Timer _updateGuiTimer;
        private bool IsSrc1Dirty { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Text = "ID Reitz - Câmera version: " + ImageBase.Version;

            // set default directory where to save the snapshots.
            textBoxImageLocation.Text = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

            // Create timer to update our UI.
            _updateGuiTimer = new Timer {Interval = 30};
            _updateGuiTimer.Tick += _updateGuiTimer_Tick;
            _updateGuiTimer.Start();

        }

        void MainWindow_Src1Changed(object sender, Flir.Atlas.Image.ImageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsSrc1Dirty = true;
        }



        void _updateGuiTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsSrc1Dirty && _cam1 != null)
            {
                // a refresh is needed of source 1
                try
                {
                    // always lock image data to prevent accessing of the image from other threads.
                    _cam1.GetImage().EnterLock();
                    pictureBoxSource1.Image = _cam1.GetImage().Image;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {


                }
                finally
                {
                    // We are done with the image data object, release.
                    _cam1.GetImage().ExitLock();
                    IsSrc1Dirty = false;
                }
            }

        }

        Camera CreateCamera(CameraDeviceInfo device)
        {
            try
            {
                if (device.SelectedStreamingFormat == ImageFormat.Argb)
                {
                    return new VideoOverlayCamera(true);
                }
                if (device.SelectedStreamingFormat == ImageFormat.FlirFileFormat)
                {
                    return new ThermalCamera(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Atlas dependencies:" + e.Message);
                Close(); 
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unsupported streaming format");
        }

        private void buttonSource1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Connect to a camera
            var device = ShowDiscovery();
            if (device == null) return;
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                _cam1.GetImage().Changed -= MainWindow_Src1Changed;
                _cam1.ConnectionStatusChanged -= _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged;
                _cam1.Disconnect();
            }
            _cam1 = CreateCamera(device);
            // Subscribe to the image changed event. Event driven gui.
            _cam1.GetImage().Changed += MainWindow_Src1Changed;
            _cam1.ConnectionStatusChanged += _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged;
            _cam1.Connect(device);
        }

        void _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged(object sender, Flir.Atlas.Live.ConnectionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BeginInvoke((Action) (() => labelStatusSrc1.Text = e.Status.ToString()));
        }





        static CameraDeviceInfo ShowDiscovery()
        {
            var dlg= new DiscoveryDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return dlg.SelectedCameraDevice;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void SaveSnapshot(Camera camera, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                camera.GetImage().EnterLock();
                if (camera.ConnectionStatus == ConnectionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    camera.GetImage().SaveSnapshot(path);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to save snapshot: " + exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                camera.GetImage().ExitLock();
            }
        }

        private void buttonSaveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // save snapshot from both sources in selected location.
            // create auto filename based on current date and time.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string filenameSrc1 = textBoxImageLocation.Text + "\\" + now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmssfff") + "_src1";

            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                SaveSnapshot(_cam1, filenameSrc1);

            }

        }

        private void MainWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                _cam1.ConnectionStatusChanged -= _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged;
                _cam1.Disconnect();
            }

        }



        private void buttonDisconnectSrc1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                _cam1.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSource1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBoxImageLocation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void labelStatusSrc1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Código do WebForm com apenas alguns botões

```
<%@ Page Title="Câmera" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="IdReitz.Contact" %>

 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
<h3>Testando a Câmera</h3>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="168px">
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="ConectaCamera" Text="Conectar Câmera" CssClass="btn btn-default" Height="27px" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="SalvarImagem" Text="Capturar Imagem" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="DesconectaCamera" Text="Desconectar" CssClass="btn btn-default" />


        <br />
        <br />
        Localização da imagem:&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxImageLocation" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="224px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />


    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Código C# do WebForm

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using Flir.Atlas.Image;    -------Essa referencia ele não reconhece --------
    using Flir.Atlas.Live.Device;
    using Flir.Atlas.Live.Discovery;

    namespace IdReitz
    {
    public partial class Camera : Page
    {

        private Camera _cam1;
        private bool IsSrc1Dirty { get; set; }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ConectaCamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Connect to a camera
            var device = ShowDiscovery();
            if (device == null) return;
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                _cam1.GetImage().Changed -= MainWindow_Src1Changed;  *******ERRO*******
                _cam1.ConnectionStatusChanged -= _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged; *******ERRO*******
                _cam1.Disconnect(); *******ERRO*******
            }
            _cam1 = CreateCamera(device);
            // Subscribe to the image changed event. Event driven gui.
            _cam1.GetImage().Changed += MainWindow_Src1Changed; *******ERRO*******
            _cam1.ConnectionStatusChanged += _cam1_ConnectionStatusChanged; *******ERRO*******
            _cam1.Connect(device); *******ERRO*******
        }

        protected void SalvarImagem(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // save snapshot from both sources in selected location.
            // create auto filename based on current date and time.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string filenameSrc1 = textBoxImageLocation.Text + "\\" + now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmssfff") + "_src1";
            string filenameSrc2 = textBoxImageLocation.Text + "\\" + now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmssfff") + "_src2";
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                SaveSnapshot(_cam1, filenameSrc1);

            }

        }

        static CameraDeviceInfo ShowDiscovery()
        {
            var dlg = new DiscoveryDialog();   *******ERRO*******
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   *******ERRO*******
            {
                return dlg.SelectedCameraDevice;
            }
            return null;
        }

        void MainWindow_Src1Changed(object sender, Flir.Atlas.Image.ImageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsSrc1Dirty = true;
        }


        Camera CreateCamera(CameraDeviceInfo device)
        {
            try
            {
                if (device.SelectedStreamingFormat == ImageFormat.Argb)
                {
                    return new VideoOverlayCamera(true);     *******ERRO*******
                }
                if (device.SelectedStreamingFormat ==  ImageFormat.FlirFileFormat)
                {
                    return new ThermalCamera(true);           *******ERRO*******
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Atlas dependencies:" + e.Message);
                Close();   *******ERRO*******
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unsupported streaming format");
        }

        static void SaveSnapshot(Camera camera, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                camera.GetImage().EnterLock();    *******ERRO*******
                if (camera.ConnectionStatus == ConnectionStatus.Connected) *******ERRO*******
                {  
                    camera.GetImage().SaveSnapshot(path);     *******ERRO*******
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to save snapshot: " + exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                camera.GetImage().ExitLock();  *******ERRO*******
            }
        }

        protected void DesconectaCamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cam1 != null)
            {
                _cam1.Disconnect();  *******ERRO*******
            }
        }


    }
 }
```

O Erro que está apresentando é:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou
>   uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um
>   programa com um formato incorreto.

..

> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.BadImageFormatException: Não foi possível
>   carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas
>   dependências. Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com
>   um formato incorreto.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual
>   solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da
>   exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de
>   exceção abaixo.
>
> Rastreamento do Carregamento de Assembly: As informações a seguir
>   podem ser úteis para determinar por que o assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image'
>   não pôde ser carregado.

=== Informações sobre estado pré-associação ===

> LOG: DisplayName = Flir.Atlas.Image  (Partial) AVI: informação de
>   associação parcial foi fornecida para um assembly: AVI: Nome do
>   Assembly: Flir.Atlas.Image | ID do Domínio: 2 AVI: uma associação
>   parcial ocorre quando somente parte do nome de exibição do assembly é
>   fornecida. AVI: isso pode fazer com que o associador carregue um
>   assembly incorreto. AVI: é recomendável fornecer uma identidade
>   textual totalmente especificada para o assembly, AVI: que consiste no
>   nome simples, na versão, na cultura e no token de chave pública. AVI:
>   Consulte o white paper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270
>   para obter mais informações e soluções comuns para o problema. LOG:
>   Appbase = file:///c:/users/reitz/documents/visual studio
>   2015/Projects/IdReitz/IdReitz/ LOG: PrivatePath inicial =
>   c:\users\reitz\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\IdReitz\IdReitz\bin Chamando assembly: (Unknown).
>   === LOG: esta associação começa no contexto de carregamento default. LOG: usando arquivo de configuração de aplicativo:
>   c:\users\reitz\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\IdReitz\IdReitz\web.config LOG: usando arquivo de
>   configuração de host:
>   C:\Users\reitz\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: usando
>   arquivo de configuração da máquina de
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: a política não está sendo aplicada para referência neste momento
>   (particular, personalizado, parcial ou associação de assembly baseada
>   em local). LOG: tentando download de nova URL
>   file:///C:/Users/reitz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/d05ad712/6abf2cb8/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL. LOG: tentando
>   download de nova URL
>   file:///C:/Users/reitz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/d05ad712/6abf2cb8/Flir.Atlas.Image/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL.
>   LOG: tentando download de nova URL
>   file:///c:/users/reitz/documents/visual studio
>   2015/Projects/IdReitz/IdReitz/bin/Flir.Atlas.Image.DLL. ERR: falha ao
>   concluir configuração do assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   encerrado.

Rastreamento de Pilha:

> [BadImageFormatException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou
>   assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma
>   tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou
>   assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma
>   tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou
>   assembly 'Flir.Atlas.Image' ou uma de suas dependências. Foi feita uma
>   tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

*Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.6.1586.0*

Comment: Basicamente não seria somente você adicionar a dll do Flir.Atlas.Image?

Comment: @PabloVargas eu já adicionei e continua o mesmo erro, como se eu não tivesse colocado mas está ali no código:


using Flir.Atlas.Image;    -------Essa referencia ele não reconhece -------

Comment: Esse Filr.Atlas, não seria somente compatível com projeto WinForms?

Comment: Lorena , pelo que pude ver algumas coisas estão faltando , por exemplo  `_cam1.GetImage().Changed -= MainWindow_Src1Changed;  *******ERRO******* ` ... isso deve ser um método que esta faltado  (`MainWindow_Src1Changed`) ... tente remover ou comenta as partes que estão com erros e vá fazendo aos poucos

Comment: Outra coisa o ConectaCamera ... Camera seria o uma câmera de um dispositivo uma web cam ? isso vai funcionar da mesma forma na aplicação web?

Comment: tente criar perguntas o mais resumido possivel para não ter votos negativos ou até mesmo acabar com a pergunta fechada.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Sim, é uma câmera termográfica, essas dlls são fornecidas pelo fabricante da câmera a função GetImage está na dll Flir.Atlas.Image que não está sendo reconhecida como se eu não tivesse inserido ela.

Comment: @PabloVargas não sei se é compatível apenas com  WinForms pq é disponibilizada pela empresa fabricante da câmera.

Comment: @Lorena, pelo que observei no site do flir essa dll é suportada no vicsual studio 2015 na versão 2.6. veja se esta na versão correta. e como falei antes, tente criar perguntas com um ou dois erros , e bem detalhadas, você pode criar quantas perguntas quiser desde que não sejam do mesmo assunto. http://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1043/~/how-can-i-get-access-to-flir-atlas-sdk-4.x-%3F

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza essa versão 2.6 seria versão do que? o visual studio que estou usando é o 2015.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53799/discussion-between-marconcilio-souza-and-lorena).